# Mixed factorial anova with one IV

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I have data that I am trying to analyse, but am not entirely sure if I am doing the right steps. It is a mixed design where every participant experienced condition A, then they were randomly assigned to condition B or C.

- Condition A: within-subjects
- Condition B & C: between-subjects (randomly assigned)

Each condition had 16 trials where a participant responded to a question with a slider from 0 to 100, then they provided their confidence for the answer on a similar type of slider. The data is not normally distributed (almost looks like a bimodal normal distribution with peaks around 35 and 65).

Most material I have come across thus far relating to mixed designs use different variables for their between and within conditions. My guess is that I would run seperate ANOVA's for the between and within trials.

Below is example data (not perfect, but close enough)

```r
library(purrr)

sample_numbers <- map_dfc(
  1:2, ~ map_dbl(
    1:(665 / 2),
    ~ {
    if (.x <= (665 / 4)) {
      mean <- 65
    } else {
      mean <- 35
    }
    rnorm(1, mean = mean, sd = 10)
  }
) %>%
  pmax(pmin(., 100), 0) %>%
  round() %>%
  c(., sample(c(0, 100), size = 167, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.5, .5))))


test_df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(LETTERS, each = 32),
  question_n = rep(1:16, times = 52), 
  value = sample_numbers[[1]],
  confidence = sample_numbers[[2]],
  condition = c(replicate(n = 13, c(rep('A', times = 16), rep('B', times = 16), rep('A', times = 16), rep('C', times = 16))))
)
```